# How can I make a > in a cell with Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an application where I can change the order and the way cards appear.  For anyone who has iOS I need something very similar to the way the Settings > Contacts > Sort Order page works.

This shows two rows.  One with First, Last and the other with Last, First.   When a user clicks on a row it acts like a radio button and a tick mark appears at the end of the row.

I would like to try and implement this functionality but I am not sure where to start.  Should I do this with a ViewCell or a TextCell and how does anyone have any ideas as to how it is implemented this

.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

***EDIT 1***: Simplified property changed logic in iOS renderer; now there are no references or handlers to cleanup.

In extension to @hankide's answer:

You can create a bindable property `IsChecked` while extending a `TextCell` or `ViewCell` and bind your VM state to it.

```
public class MyTextCell : TextCell
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty IsCheckedProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            "IsChecked", typeof(bool), typeof(MyTextCell),
            defaultValue: false);

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsCheckedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Next step would be to create renderer that listens to this property and shows a check-mark at iOS level.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyTextCell), typeof(SampleApp.iOS.MyTextCellRenderer))]
namespace SampleApp.iOS
{
    public class MyTextCellRenderer : TextCellRenderer
    {
        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
        {
            var nativeCell = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);

            var formsCell = item as MyTextCell;
            SetCheckmark(nativeCell, formsCell);

            return nativeCell;
        }

        protected override void HandlePropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            base.HandlePropertyChanged(sender, args);

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"HandlePropertyChanged {args.PropertyName}");
            if (args.PropertyName == MyTextCell.IsCheckedProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                var nativeCell = sender as CellTableViewCell;
                if (nativeCell?.Element is MyTextCell formsCell)
                    SetCheckmark(nativeCell, formsCell);
            }
        }

        void SetCheckmark(UITableViewCell nativeCell, MyTextCell formsCell)
        {
            if (formsCell.IsChecked)
                nativeCell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark;
            else
                nativeCell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.None;
        }
    }
}
```

**Sample usage 1**

And, sample usage would like:

```
<TableView Intent="Settings">
    <TableSection Title="Sort Order">
        <local:MyTextCell Text="First Last" IsChecked="false" />
        <local:MyTextCell Text="Last, First" IsChecked="true" />
    </TableSection>
</TableView>
```

**Sample usage 2**

You can also listen to `Tapped` event to ensure `IsChecked` property works as expected.

For example, you bind this property to ViewModel:

```
<TableView Intent="Settings">
    <TableSection Title="Sort Order">
        <local:MyTextCell Tapped="Handle_Tapped" Text="{Binding [0].Name}" IsChecked="{Binding [0].IsSelected}" />
        <local:MyTextCell Tapped="Handle_Tapped" Text="{Binding [1].Name}" IsChecked="{Binding [1].IsSelected}" />
    </TableSection>
</TableView>
```

and handle tap event:

```
public SettingViewModel[] Settings = new []{
    new SettingViewModel { Name = "First Last", IsSelected = false },
    new SettingViewModel { Name = "Last First", IsSelected = true },
};

void Handle_Tapped(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var cell = sender as TextCell;
    if (cell == null)
        return;

    var selected = cell.Text;
    foreach(var setting in Settings)
    {
        if (setting.Name == selected)
            setting.IsSelected = true;
        else
            setting.IsSelected = false;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I have added a bounty and awarded this to you.

Comment: Bounty added by me as Anne works with me and she asked me to add it.  Thanks for the very good answer.

Comment: Thanks. Happy to know the answer helped :)

Answer (score 7):

The sort order settings page you described is implemented using the UIKit's `UITableView`. In Xamarin.Forms, you can utilize the [TableView](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/tableview/) control to get the same result.

As you will quickly notice, there's no way to set the checkmark icon with Xamarin.Forms so you'll probably need to create a [custom cell](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/tableview/#Custom_Cells), that has the text on the left and the checkmark image on the right.

If you really want to do everything by the book, you should probably create a custom renderer that allows you to set the [Accessory](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/UIKit.UITableViewCellAccessory/) property of the current `ViewCell`. However, this will get a bit complex for such a small feature.

Comment: Your Accessory link leads to a 404 page.

Comment: @Physikbuddha Thanks for the heads up, I fixed the link.